# Cannot get results from json API

Tags: arrays, json, angular, rest

I am trying to get results from an json api. I believe the error has to do with the data being nested in the array. I am able to console.log my data from the api and it looks as such.

[image]

However, I am unable to display me results in my html. I have looked at other questions such as this but to no avail.

ts.

```
 getApiResult(){
    if(this.searchvalue != null && this.searchyear != null){
      this.apiService.loadAll(this.searchvalue,this.searchyear).subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data
        console.log(data)
      });
    }
  }
```

html.

```
<div *ngFor="article of data;index as i">
                <div class="card" class="cardpadding">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" class="display-4" style="font-size: 32px; text-align: center;">
                            {{article.Results[i].Model_Name}}
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Tell us about the errors you see in the console?

Comment: no errors in the console unfortunately

Comment: you should loop through data.Results, ie.  instead of `article of data`. it should be `article of data.Results`. alternatively in subscribe call you can set `this.data = data.Results;` after checking error codes and all that. Also dont forget to change in mustache expression to `{{article.Model_Name}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, its not `<div class="card" class="cardpadding">` but rather `<div class="card cardpadding">` with class names in one attribute separated by `<space>`. In your example only the last class gets applied.
About your data: You assign this.data = data. Where data is just an object.
Instead you should change the *ngFor to

```
*ngFor="article of data.Results"
```

and later use article directly without the index i.

```
{{article.Model_Name}}
```

Edit: I just realized you are also missing the "let" in the *ngFor
e.g.

```
*ngFor="let article of data.Results"
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have wrong dataType for ngFor. From your code it shows data is not an array rather just a single object. I thik you should iterate data.Results.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing below html template with yours. You are wrongly iterating.

```
<div *ngFor="article of data.Results;index as i">
            <div class="card" class="cardpadding">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title" class="display-4" style="font-size: 32px; text-align: center;">
                        {{article.Model_Name}}
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```